# Django tutorial part 3: adding "namespacing" change breaks it

Tags: python, django, namespaces

Part 3 of the [django 1.9 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names) covers a lot of ground. When I got up to "Namespacing URL names"
and added to "polls/urls.py"

```
...
app_name = 'polls'
...
```

and updated "polls/index.html"
with the new namespaced url:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

and run it, I now get the error:
"u'polls' is not a registered namespace"

Did I miss another line somewhere else to register the namespace?  Anyone else have this problem?  I don't want to skip over to the next chapter until I fix the problem!

Comment: Unless there can never be more than one django tutorial, it would be a good idea to edit your question to include a link to Part 3 of the tutorial you are following.

Comment: hyperlink added in first sentence!

Comment: Which version of Django do you have? Because the tutorial is for v1.9 and it won't work for previous versions. To check your Django version, do this in Python shell: `import django`, then `django.get_version()`.

Comment: Yes, I had the wrong version.  This tutorial doesn't like django v1.8.4.

Answer (score 0):

Check your urls.py for your project (not the Polls app, but the 'mysite' project -- in the same dir where settings.py is).  On the line where you import your URLs from your polls app, include the namespace there too.

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")
```

Comment: Actually, the way OP is doing it, [works for v1.9](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs). Although your answer is correct, it doesn't clarify why it's not working for OP.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for the link to the explanation in the difference between 1.9 and previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot.  I was running django 1.8.4.  Used pip --upgrade and now it runs like a star in version 1.9.
It just shows how long ago I started trying to learn this stuff.  Thanks for the help.